# Is it possible to use an expression tree to define a method body for dynamic types?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

If I'm creating a dynamic type like so:

```
TypeBuilder dynaType = dynaModule.DefineType(typeof(T).Name + "_ORMProxy");

dynaType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IServiceTable));

// (1) Implement: (String) IServiceTable.TableName { get; }
FieldBuilder tableNameField = dynaType.DefineField("tableName", typeof(String), FieldAttributes.Private);
MethodBuilder tableNamePublicGetAccessor = dynaType.DefineMethod("get_tableName", MethodAttributes.Public);
tableNamePublicGetAccessor...
```

Is it possible to set the `GetAccessor` method to an expression tree. They're much easier to work with than straight IL.

Comment: BTW, the common naming convention for property accessors is `get_X`, not `X_get`. Though it most likely won't matter.

Comment: It does actually, I'll change my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.  The `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod()` method will let you compile an expression tree to a `MethodBuilder` **only if** the method is static.  It cannot be used to implement instance methods, which I believe is what you want in your example.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you're right. Though it doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: My Java implementation of LINQ expression trees does not have that limitation :).

Comment: If you can do LINQ in Java, I would like to know how x 10 million.

Comment: LINQ is something of an overloaded term.  What I have done is implement LINQ/DLR the expression tree API and compiler (with some enhancements).  I use this purely for doing runtime code generation.  It has nothing to do with the collection/query-related aspects of LINQ.  I just prefer working with declarative expression trees to raw bytecode :).

Comment: I see. `I just prefer working with declarative expression trees to raw bytecode` - definitely this.

Comment: Well then, [have fun](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon) :D.  There's not much documentation (sorry!), but if you know System.Linq.Expressions and System.Reflection, it should be pretty easy to figure out.  WIP documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Expressions%20Framework).

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what [the `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728224.aspx) is for.

Answer (score 2):

A little trick I'm using (which is still buggy) is to create 2 functions with identical signatures, 1 static an 1 taking an instance. The Expression Tree gets compiled using the MethodBuilder and you create an (almost) identical signature (with a new MethodBuilder) for which you emit the IL needed to invoke the static 'twin' function.

An example would go like this (in C#):

```
//You create a static function (from ExpressionTree) matching signature:
static void MyInstanceFunction(object, string, string, string);

//Then create an instance (HasThis) function matching:
void MyInstanceFunction(string, string, string);
```

You then use Reflection.Emit on the instance MethodBuilder to Emit:

1. Some calls to retrieve the MethodInfo of the static function (You can't know this until 'CreateType' is called) so we need to get it through the IL equivalent of this.GetType().GetMethod(...)
2. Copy the arguments passed into the function (including 'this' which is LdArg_0) to an array of object
3. Call the "Invoke" function directly

I was a little apprehensive about going this route (because of the convoluted public API). However, I really needed the types to have properly declared (and working) instance methods and not just mimic instance behaviour. This seems to do the trick so far.

Comment: Great answer

I'd like to add, that you can use OpCodes.Tailcall   to get performance increase.